# Google not re-crawling subpages after "fetch as Google" with the "directly linked pages" option

Tags: web-crawlers, noindex

After fixing a "noindex" issue on my WordPress website, where all my pages failed to be crawled by Google, I used Google Webmaster to re-index the website (without waiting). But it worked only for the home page although I requested re-crawl of any directly-linked pages as well.

Example of a sub page that initially didn't get indexed:

```
http://www.trophit.com/index.php/what-is-trophit/
```

If I manually tell GW to crawl each page URL, then it does it, but that's not acceptable. Something still blocks Google from properly crawling the entire site on its own... Any ideas?

Comment: How long have you waited after submitting the request to checking the index?

Comment: In my experience, it can take a month to recover from noindex mistakes with Google.   There is no way to force Google to recrawl and reindex the entire site quickly.

Comment: People like to poke the bear don't they. They poke and say, "Hurry the hell up!", over and over again. Do you think that is a wise thing to do? Leave Google alone. You will get what you want, just be patient Grasshopper!.

Comment: My expectation for "near instant" reindex is only because I've read so online. If that is not the case and you have experienced otherwise, thanks to the info. I wonder, however, why the urls that I did submit instantly appear on Google search but not any of their direct sub pages... There are only a few sub pages, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going out on a limb and since there is no word of it. I will answer based on experience.

**Submit a sitemap > then fetch as Google (usually takes a couple of minutes) > submit to index.**

Creating a sitemap in [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/)

I have had a client ask me to use index, nofollow
They were crawled, then asked me to change to index, follow and it was updated within 1 week.

I have had sites live for long periods, without submitting a sitemap and only the home page was indexed.

Of course nothing is 100% when Google is concerned but you can narrow it down rather quickly.

Comment: Ah, the plugin thing worked as you said. I installed it, then submitted the result xml to google and voila, site:trophit.com query now shows all the results. It only took a few minutes. Thank you!